# importing excel table into database

Tags: sql, excel, import

I have a following table in xlsx format which I would like to import into the my sql database:

[image]

The table is pretty complicated and I only want the records after '1)HEADING'

I have been looking at php libraries to import into sql but they only seem to be for simple excel files.

Comment: You need a tool for your DBMS which recognises EXCEL ranges, ODBC for example. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844633/using-excel-as-an-odbc-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to realize that :

**First method :**

1) Export it into some text format. The easiest will probably be a tab-delimited version, but CSV can work as well.

2) Use the load data capability. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

3) Look half way down the page, as it will gives a good example for tab separated data:

FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\'

4) Check your data. Sometimes quoting or escaping has problems, and you need to adjust your source, import command-- or it may just be easier to post-process via SQL.

**Second method :**

There's a simple online tool that can do this called [sqlizer.io](https://sqlizer.io).

[image]

You upload an XLSX file to it, enter a sheet name and cell range, and it will generate a CREATE TABLE statement and a bunch of INSERT statements to import all your data into a MySQL database.