# I have multiple tables which i need to combine onto one table with an excel formula.

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have multiple tables which i need to combine onto one table there are no duplicate entries, all the column headings are the same but there will be empty fields!

I could acheive the result by copying and pasting the data into the restults table which would do the job however it wouldn't update iself.

It should be very easy. I needs to be a formula of some kind so that it will update itself when the original tables are updated?

There is probably a very straight forward solution and i am probably over complicating it.

can somebody help me? :)

Comment: _I have multiple tables_ where are they?

Answer (score 0):

`no duplicate entries` use a `Select distinct (query)`and `Union all` to generate the data in an excel sheet you can use an [ODBC connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844633/using-excel-as-an-odbc-database) within excel.  Or of course export the table