# Simple way to add new records in Excel based on another source (excel spreadsheet)

Tags: excel, database, f#, powerquery, m

I have the list of users in Excel file which I use as a source of data (**source.xls**). It contains fields like name, surname, initials. 
I have another Excel spreadsheet where I manage those users with additional information (i.e. account creation/close date). Let's call the second spreadsheet **accounts.xls** and the workbook "***Active***".
Whenever a new user is added to the **source.xls** file, I would like to be able to add the record/user to the **accounts.xls**. And when the user is deleted from **source.xls**, I would like to move the record from "***Active***" worksheet to "***Deleted***" and put update the close date in the **accounts.xls** file.

What approach would you suggest to achieve that with the least amount of effort?

The unique data is a combination of name+surname+initals.

Comment: As it stands I think your question is too broad, there are lots of ways to interact with Excel, via COM https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/302084/how-to-automate-microsoft-excel-from-microsoft-visual-c-net, via ODBC https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844633/using-excel-as-an-odbc-database or many of the packages described here: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=XLSX.

Comment: Seems like you should be storing users in a database instead of Excel. If you want to stick with Excel, you might be able to "catch" users being deleted or added with the `Worksheet_Change` event -- or build an interface/user form that add/deletes for you.

Comment: Move that to SQL. You can get MS SQL Express for free: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express

Comment: Thx for answers. 
KonstantinKonstantinov - unfortunately I do not have a choice as it has to be this way.  
@chillin Actually in the accounts.xls I have created the connection to the XLS file as data source and pointed out source.xls file and the first workbook. In the Power Query Editor filtered out empty rows. So far I can say, I got the database. But the Power Query Editor works on F# and this is definitely not my strength. Now how to select records which don't exist in acounts.xls and append them to the Active workbook?
Probably I need to use COM pointed out by Jackson.