# Reading an excel file using SQL queries in oracle sql developer

Tags: excel, oracle

I am looking for a way to read the excel file using sql queries in oracle sql developer. dont need a solution where i need to install additional plugins,libraries or need to enable a config etc. i need to update multiple tables using the data from the excel sheet. the excel may have any number of rows and columns. if i can do this using csv that is also fine.

i know i can insert data from excel directly into a table but that is not for me. i need to be able to traverse through the excel file and update the tables using sql queries.

Comment: SQL Developer does not have a SQL runtime engine to parse and compile queries. It must connect to some other service - like Oracle RDBMS, or a supported ODBC data source connection - to compile and execute SQL statements. It doesn't edit spreadsheets directly. Check out this answer for setting up Excel as an ODBC data source, but note that in general this approach is ***NOT recommended***. This will also require use of a separate Oracle Client with Oracle's ODBC drivers, so not sure this meets your requirements. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844633/using-excel-as-an-odbc-database

Comment: Have you looked at the APEX_DATA_PARSER package that is included with Oracle APEX? https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/aeapi/PARSE-Function.html#GUID-B815CF74-C469-4F78-9433-643D1339E930